# Java Springboot Gradle project how to write log to cloudwatch?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, log4j2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have configured log4j2 in my gradle project to write the log to a local file. The log4j2.xml file is written as follow:

```
<Configuration>  
    <appender name="cloud-watch" class="io.github.dibog.AwsLogAppender">
            <awsConfig>
                <credentials>
                    <accessKeyId>XXXXX</accessKeyId>
                    <secretAccessKey>XXXXXX</secretAccessKey>
                </credentials>
                <region>us-east-2</region>        
            </awsConfig>

            <createLogGroup>true</createLogGroup>
            <queueLength>100</queueLength>
            <groupName>SpringLog</groupName>
            <streamName>StreamName</streamName>
            <dateFormat>yyyyMMdd_HHmm</dateFormat>
             <layout>
                <pattern>[%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
             </layout>
        </appender>       
        <Loggers>
        <Root level="ALL">
            <AppenderRef ref="cloud-watch"/>
        </Root>
        </Loggers>
    
    
    
</Configuration>
```

Here I am firstly getting an error  "Unable to locate appender "cloud-watch". Also the logging to the cloudwatch is also not working.

Can any one please correct me what I am doing wrong. Your help is much appreciated. I tried consoling the log and it works fine.

Can anyone suggest on how to do logging from springboot gradle project to aws cloudwatch?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid Log4j2 configuration. Log4j2 uses plugins and the class name of appenders, filters, layouts, etc is never specified in the configuration.

I found an example configuration similar to yours at https://github.com/dibog/cloudwatch-logback-appender. Note that the name of the project is cloudwatch-logback-appender, so this appender is designed to work with Logback, not Log4j2.

Comment: Thanks @rgoers for the response. I actually tried with the new logback.xml as you just mentioned. Now am not getting any errors but nothing is written to the cloudwatch either. Should i include some package  in the build.gradle file?

Comment: Can I get a sample gradle project where logging works to cloudwatch?

Comment: Not from me. I don’t use Gradle.